# Regex to identify for values other than alphanumeric values which can have hyphen or dot in between them but not at beginning or at end

Tags: regex

I am new to the regular expressions. I have seen other quite close posts with a similar question but as you are aware in RegEx even dot matters a lot so here I am posting this question to seek help in this particular scenario.

1. My SQL column value can have a-z, A-Z, and 0-9
2. It can have a dot(.) and hyphen(-) in between. These 2 things cannot be at the beginning or at the end.
3. It cannot have space or tabs or any blanks anywhere in the column value.
4. It cannot start or end with any special characters; not even dots or hyphens.

I wrote this query which covers the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd points but fails in the 4th case.

```
select * from test_db.xtmp_testtable_invalidchars042321_rg  where (sl_id  REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]].+$')

**Table column input values**
 RaghavGupta
.RaghavGupta
@Raghav.Gupta
"Raghav Gupta"
Raghav Gupta
Raghav#Gupta
Raghav$Gupta
Raghav%Gupta
Raghav*Gupta
Raghav.Gupta
RaghavGupta
RaghavGupta$
RaghavGupta.
RaghavGupta[]

**Query Result**    
 RaghavGupta    
.RaghavGupta    
@Raghav.Gupta   
"Raghav Gupta"  
Raghav  Gupta
Raghav#Gupta    
Raghav$Gupta    
Raghav%Gupta    
Raghav*Gupta    
Raghav.Gupta    
"RaghavGupta        "   
RaghavGupta[]
```

Comment: Try `REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+([.-][[:alnum:]]+)*$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -  Seems to be working. Yet to test on the huge table though. Could you please explain the entire regexp character by character? Also kindly post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT` with the *matching* regex:

```sql
select * from test_db.xtmp_testtable_invalidchars042321_rg  where (sl_id NOT REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+([.-][[:alnum:]]+)*$')
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars (`[:alnum:]` is a POSIX character class that matches letters and/or digits)
- `([.-][[:alnum:]]+)*` - (a capturing group that matches) zero or more repetitions of

  - `[.-]` - a `.` or `-`
- `[[:alnum:]]+` - one or more alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that I need the reverse which means it does not pass the condition. Like erroneous records. Like I mentioned in the query results in the question.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta So, you need to use `NOT REGEXP`.

Comment: Ohh yes!! Let me test it on the huge table and revert. Thanks for the quick answer.